# Read from config into a method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a method:

```
public function getAllRecords($perPage = 10){
    ....
}
```

If per page is not specified, it will get 10.

I would like to read this figure from config.

I've tried:

```
public function getAllRecords($perPage = config('db.perPage')){
```

But I get an error.

How can I read config into a method like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a constructor and get this stuff there:

```
protected $perPage;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->perPage = config(db.perPage);
}

public function getAllRecords($perPage = $this->perPage)
{
```

Or you could just do this:

```
public function getAllRecords($perPage = null)
{
    $perPage = is_null($perPage) ? config('db.perPage') : $perPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do something like this:

```
public function getAllRecords($perPage = null)
{
    if (is_null($perPage)) {
        $perPage = config('db.perPage');
    }

    // ...
}
```